# JUnit - Rerun Tests in same order through Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testing, junit

I would like to be able to re-run a group of unit tests in the same order they were previously run.

Yes, I understand that running test in a random order is better in general, because you will uncover bugs that may be covered up in one particular test ordering.

HOWEVER, once you find a bug which is based on test order it would be extremely useful to re-run the tests in same order over and over so you can debug.  Is there anyway to do this through Eclipse/Junit?

Answer (score 1):

JUNIt does not guarantee an order running as you mentioned yourself. But you can build dependencies when you write just a test function which calls all other test-methods but this methods should not be annotated. So you always would run the tests in the same order, but you couldn't test them seperately.

Another approach is to use Testframeworks which enables dependancy-management.
Therefore have a look at TestNG (another very good Java Test-Framework) or JExample (builds on JUnit Visit http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~akuhn/blog/2008/jexample-quickstart/ for a short introduction)

Comment: Well its better than nothing, but with ~500 tests it would take a long time to go through and hand code this test function.  I guess you could parse the junit log and then generate the code to rerun the tests in order but it really seems like an Eclipse feature someone needs to implement.